# Change variables in double integral

Tags: integration

I have to evaluate
$$\iint_{R}\frac{\sin(x-y)}{\cos(x+y)}dxdy$$
where $R$ is bounded by $0\leq x+y\leq1,x\geq0,y\geq0$. My first thought was to change the variables to
$$u=x-y$$
$$v=x+y$$
Since $0\leq x+y\leq 1$, then it's clear
$$0\leq v\leq1$$

However, is there a way I could find the limits of integration for $u$?

Comment: I mean your transformation is basically a 45° rotation, and your initial domain a triangle, so you'll get another triangle with hypotenuse parallel to x-axis. So take the 3 summits $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ and see how they transform.

Comment: You have $-v\le u\le v$. Can you show each such choice of $u$ with $v\in[0,\,1]$ corresponds to one choice of $x,\,y\ge0$? (By the way, you can evaluate this integral simply by considering what happens when you reflect in $y=x$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your change of variables,
$$u=x-y, \\ v=x+y,$$
it is clear that
$$y=\frac{v-u}{2}, \\ x=\frac{v+u}{2}.$$
Now, since $0\leq x+y\leq 1$, it follows that $0\leq v\leq 1$. We now focus on the other two conditions:

- $\displaystyle x\geq 0\iff \frac{v+u}{2}\geq 0\iff u\geq -v$
- $\displaystyle y\geq 0\iff \frac{v-u}{2}\geq 0\iff u\leq v$

and we can sum up the two conditions by saying that $-v\leq u\leq v.$